# os.chdir relative path error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import os,pdb
import sys
print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
pdb.set_trace()
os.chdir('../bci_framework')
```

Output:

```
D:\baseline\BCI-Comparison-Framework\bci_framework
WindowsError: (2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', '../bci_framework')
```

Why? The folder is present!

Comment: What's your current path? '..' on UNIX-like systems means "go back a folder", to my knowledge.

Comment: Confirmed that the same is true for windows: http://www.7tutorials.com/command-prompt-how-use-basic-commands. Perhaps try changing the ".." to "." if you're meaning to refer to your current directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *file* is in the directory `bci_framework`, which is why printing out it's path shows you that directory, but *you* aren't.  Wherever you are, it doesn't have `bci_framework` as a sibling.

Print out `os.getcwd()` to determine your current location.  Any relative paths to `chdir` will be relative to that location, not to the location of the file.

For example, if you are in the `stackoverflow` directory below, and run `python ./abhishek/bci_framework/my_file.py`, your current directory is `stackoverflow`.  Going up one directory will not contain the `bci_framework` directory.

```
stackoverflow/
    davidism/
    abhishek/
        bci_framework/
            my_file.py
```